# RestAssured. StackOverflowError when assign a String to baseUri

Tags: java, rest, automation, rest-assured

I'm getting a StackOverflow error when i assign a String to BaseURi.

baseURI  = Apis.REQUEST_TOKEN;

The "Apis.REQUEST_TOKEN" is a String that comes fron another class.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I had to read this 3 times, finally a StackOverflow error on StackOverflow!  You should update your tags to include which language you are making the request with.

Comment: Oh thanks! Sorry but i have no idea about how to update my tags... Can you help me please?

Comment: Sure thing!  Under your question you should see 'share' 'edit' and 'flag'.  Just click edit and at the bottom of the page is where you can add tags.  Just throw in what language you are using and your question will show up in the right searches where people can help you.

Comment: Oh thanks!! I've just did it.

Comment: Perfect, now your question should get some help :)